# Cancel hurting animation

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am making a mod that adds armor that makes you invincible. So far I have this code:

```
@SubscribeEvent
public void onPlayerHurt(LivingHurtEvent event) {
    if(event.getEntity() != null && event.getEntity() instanceof  EntityPlayer){
        EntityPlayer player = (EntityPlayer) event.getEntity();
        for(ItemStack stack : player.getArmorInventoryList()) {
            if(stack != null && stack.getItem() instanceof ItemUltimusArmor){
                event.setCanceled(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This does cancel the damage when I am using my armor, but I still get the noise and animation. While wearing this armor, I want to be able to not have that stuff. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Does using `LivingAttackEvent` work?  (That event occurs when an entity is attacked).  If not, an alternative would be to somehow cancel the animation directly - the animation is triggered in `EntityLivingBase.handleStatusUpdate` (see [wiki.vg's article on entities](http://wiki.vg/Entities#Living)) - I don't know if forge has a hook for that or not, but it's a potential lead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I used the `LivingAttackEvent` to listen for an event, literaly used the same code as the `LivingHurtEvent`, and it worked. Thank you to Pokechu22 for suggesting this!